# Build succeeded but publish failed in VS 2013 for WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013, publish

This question was already asked so many times. But the said solutions did not help. I tried to publish the WCF project. But it build successfully but failed on publish. I get the following message in output window.

[image: Output window]

I tried the following things

1. Checked the VS2013 having administrator rights.
2. Folders have permission to modify.
3. Changed the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" option to "Detailed"

above things did not give me solution. I attached my solution explorer for reference.

[image: Solution Explorer]

How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: From your screenshot It doesn't look like you turned on verbosity=detailed

Comment: Thanks for your response. It will not giving detailed info for publish alone. Building process will give detailed info. I changed the screen shot. Please refer it.

Comment: Where is it trying to write to on publish? is that still accessible?

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120812/publish-failed-but-build-succeeded) helps you

Comment: @BugFinder: Thanks for response. Yes it is accessible. Actually, I have two projects, Application and WCF. Application is publish successfully. WCF only unsuccessful. I tried to publish same directory itself. But no use.

Comment: @Disappointed: Actually I tried all the answers on that question. No use.

Comment: @BugFinder: This project was worked and published successful when it was in VS2010. Now I changed it to VS2013. Then only problem starts.

Comment: Downgrading my Microsoft.Net.Compilers to 2.4.0 (FINALLY!) fixed this for me.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104124/826308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into this issue before, the latest was while upgrading a WCF project from Visual Studio 2013 to 2015. The solution (with multiple projects) would build and run fine within VS but would fail when publishing the WCF service. No error in the publish step just the message:

```
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The solution has always been in the project properties. In the latest case, was the Build > Platform Target which was setup as x64 by default in VS2015, which I changed to "Any CPU" and resolved my issue. I hope it helps.