# Project builds but can't publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have an MVC project that for an uknown reason refuses to publish to a local folder in the PC.

The log says the following:

```
3>------ Publish started: Project: Admin, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
3>Connecting to D:\Deploys...
3>Project "Admin.csproj" (GatherAllFilesToPublish target(s)):
3>    Building with tools version "14.0".
3>    Target "ValidateMSBuildToolsVersion" skipped. Previously built unsuccessfully.
3>Done building project "Admin.csproj" -- FAILED.
3>
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I haven't had a problem debugging on either release or debug config.

Comment: What does a more verbose output say? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/10/07/did-you-know-you-can-configure-the-msbuild-verbosity-in-the-output-window-329/

Comment: @Caramiriel Hi! I already have it on the "diagnostic" option. The "detailed" one also outputs the same.

Comment: try a clean/rebuild. restart visual studio.

Comment: @JMawer Hi! Already did that. Delete obj/bin folders, restart VS, restart PC.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have permission to publish to that folder location?  Have you tried installing to a location you are certain you have read/write permissions?

Comment: See my answer - hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120812/publish-failed-but-build-succeeded/49354473#49354473

Answer (score 67, accepted):

So I made it work.

The problem was the version of the "Microsoft.Net.Compilers". I downgraded from  v2.6.1 to v2.4.0.

I don't know why so if someone knows it would be cool to know.

Comment: Thanks this problem was getting on my nerves, would really want to know why this is happening.

Comment: Not just an issue with web publish; I had the problem that my solution rebuild was always failing because of this (two MVC projects, one as a dependency of the other the second one would always fail if the first one still needed to be built).

Comment: According to [https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/NuGet-packages] the 2+ versions of the compilers package are for VS2017 and C#7. Also see [https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/19128] for what's supported where. Why it actually works with 2.4 and not with 2.6.1 (it shouldn't work with 2.4 either); I can only imagine the build tasks were updated with 2.4 but not with 2.6.1 so 2.6.1 requires MSBUILD 15 again (VS2015 has MSBUILD 14).

Comment: Going to 2.4.0 fixed for me as well. Per dup suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272051/publish-failed-build-succeeded?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment83528196_48272051

Comment: I had the same problem too! Thanks!

Comment: I also had this problem (running under Visual Studio 2015). Upgrading Microsoft.Net.Compilers to 2.7.0 (published 2018-03-08) solved it.

Comment: Had the same, I just uninstalled .Net.Compilers. also solved the problem

Comment: What a PITA! Worked for me as well!

Comment: I used the VS2015 and got the same issue. this worked for me and fixed the issue

Comment: I resolved it by removing the compiler reference as it wasn't needed. Still don't know how it got added in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for reopening the thread, but for me Cleaning the solution worked on .NET.Compilers v2.7 (Visual Studio 2015).

Comment: The same worked for me in VS2017, along with deleting all the existing `obj` and `bin` folders in sub-projects.

Answer (score 1):

downgrade "Microsoft.Net.Compilers" from v2.9.0 to v2.4.0 works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my issue altogether by removing the NuGet package "Microsoft.Net.Compilers", rather than downgrade to 2.4.0.

(For quite some time, the Publish error would disappear if I simply restarted VS, but eventually that stopped working.)

Answer (score 1):

First, select the mode (Debug or Release). Then right click on the solution/project then select Clean. Then choose Rebuild. Then Publish.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me, it turned out to be a simple case of using an int in a ViewComponent call from a razor template, when that argument should have been a Guid. For some reason Intellisense didn't pick it up, I had to turn on detailed verbosity to see the error in the build process.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Asp.net Core 2 MVC 2.1
So there was no Microsoft.Net.Compilers in my solution.  I tried to rebuild all projects, unload / load again but there was no change.

1) So, I have upgraded VS 2017 15.7.3 to 15.8.7
2) Then deleted all bin/release directory contents from each projects in solution.
3) Then deleted all obj directory contents from each projects in solution.
4) Then rebuilded all projects one by one.
Then tried to publish and it succeded.

Maybe if I tried from step 2 in old Visual Studio it would be succed.

Answer (score 0):

### Try opening the solution with Visual Studio 2017

I had been building and publishing from Visual Studio 2015, as that is the version of Visual Studio that the Version Selector picked when I opened the solution file.

I tried opening my solution file from Visual Studio 2017 instead, and that succeeded in publishing.

Answer (score 0):

I had switched to `C# 7.3` in *Properties > Build > Advanced*, but accidentally only did so for the **Debug** configuration. When publishing (using **Release** configuration) it was still using `C# 7.0`, which lacked some of the language features I had used.

Errors weren't visible in the **Error List** pane, only in the **Output** pane.

Setting the language version to `C# 7.3` for **"All Configurations"** solved it for me.

This was using current version of Visual Studio 2017, `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` package *not* included in project.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` Nuget package.

I had tried a lot of things, none successful. I did this and the publishing succeeded. To be sure, I restored my project from BitBucket to its original condition, tested to see the publishing failed, removed the nuget package again, and it worked.

Comment: Welcome! I edited your question to help with clarity. Thanks for finding this solution!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The project was building okay but when I published it Azure send me errors.

My project target .NET framework was 4.6.2 version and I was upgrading Nugget packages, unfortunatelly I upgraded my .NET Compilers to last version and it wasnt compatible to my target .NET version.You should be able to see it here:

[Description of .NET Compilers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1MuE.png)

[My target framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Taknj.png)

I fixed it by downgrading .NET Compilers to a version compatible to my .NET Framework (In my case, to use 4.6.2 framework I need to use .NET Compiller 2.10).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with project using:

1. .NET 4.7.2
2. MVC5 solution
3. All unit test files with file name format: Tests.cs like "HomeControllerTest.cs"
4. Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019, Version 16.6.4

For that project, the following Azure DevOps Pipeline settings works:

**MSBuild arguments:**

/t:Publish;Build /p:PublishDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\" /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\"

**Visual Studio Test Platform Installer**: Latest stable

**Select test using**: Test assemblies

Testfiles:
***Tests*.dll

!**\obj**

**Searchfolder**:$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

**Test results folder**: $(Agent.TempDirectory)\TestResults

**Test platform version**: Installed by Tools Installer

**Other console options**: /Framework:Framework45 /Diag:log.txt /Logger:console

**Build platform**: $(BuildPlatform)

**Build configuration**: $(BuildConfiguration)

===
YAML

steps:

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution ***.sln'
  inputs:
  solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
  msbuildArgs: '/t:Publish;Build /p:PublishDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\" /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\" '
  platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
  configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
  clean: true
  maximumCpuCount: true
  restoreNugetPackages: true
  createLogFile: true

steps:

- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Visual Studio Test Platform Installer'
  inputs:
  versionSelector: latestStable

steps:

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
  testAssemblyVer2: |
  ***Tests*.dll
  !**\obj**
  vsTestVersion: toolsInstaller
  otherConsoleOptions: '/Framework:Framework45 /Diag:log.txt /Logger:console'
  platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
  configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
  diagnosticsEnabled: true

steps:

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results **/TEST-*.xml'
  inputs:
  testResultsFormat: VSTest