# Publish failed Build succeeded

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

Hi someone can help with that?

```
2>Build succeeded.
2>
2>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.18
3>------ Publish started: Project: WebApi, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
3>Connecting to C:\Web\WebApi...
3>Project "WebApi.csproj" (GatherAllFilesToPublish target(s)):
3>    Building with tools version "14.0".
3>    Target "ValidateMSBuildToolsVersion" skipped. Previously built unsuccessfully.
3>Done building project "WebApi.csproj" -- FAILED.
3>
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

i was try:
- cleaning/rebuilding solution
- changing project targert to x86,x64 and back to Any
- deleting file from bin folder
- restarting pc

I use VS2015 with admin rights.

Comment: What version of the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` package do you have?

Comment: Microsoft.Net.Compilers 2.6.1

Comment: Can you try downgrading it to version v2.4.0?

Comment: hmm it works with 2.4.0 . Thank you, but why its failed with 2.6.1 its some bug or some fix exist ?

Comment: No idea, I just Googled the error and found this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103014/project-builds-but-cant-publish

Comment: Ok Thank you i was miss that :)

Comment: DEAR LORD! ... Thank you DavidG (and others in related threads who said same)! That was my issue and going back to 2.4.0 fixed it! FINALLY I have successful builds **AND** publishing!