# I can not publish the project Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to publish the project, but it gives a publishing error. I tried, but I could not find the right solution.

[image: you can examine the error.]

Error Building with Tools version "14.0"

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/A15pNr.jpg

Picture Adress

Comment: Try to look if your solution has any build errors.

Comment: It is not enough to help you. The only thing I can see there is that the problem is in the AdminWeb project

Comment: Can you successfully build your project? I don’t think so.

Comment: Build no problem. My problem is publish. ToolVersion 14.0. I search to error not answer

Comment: Please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103014/project-builds-but-cant-publish

Comment: İ see but not answer. I've tried