# Visual Studio 2015. Unable to publish my project - appears to build fine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, publish

Visual Studio 2015.update3 - fully updated & patched - windows 8.1 - .net 4.7.1

```
2>------ Publish started: Project: Prometheus, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>Connecting to C:\Temp\publish...
2>Project "test.csproj" (GatherAllFilesToPublish target(s)):
2>    Building with tools version "14.0".
2>    Target "ValidateMSBuildToolsVersion" skipped. Previously built unsuccessfully.
2>Done building project "test.csproj" -- FAILED.
2>
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, **1 failed**, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have searched and tried every solution online - no joy. Have spent over 3 days trying to sort this out - getting super frustrated now. It appears to build fine but always fails to publish to a local folder on the pc.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

**Note**: I have tried Any CPU, Debug, and Release configurations - all end the same. I have configured the build to output diagnostic information which is available on request.

Comment: have you tried running your visual studio in Admin mode?

Comment: tried Admin mode. no difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Project builds but can't publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103014/project-builds-but-cant-publish)

Comment: had a look. down graded the dotnet compiler to 2.7.0. No difference. Full cleanup of obj, bin directories. tried an alternate local path. - builds fine everythime,  but publish still fails. :-(

Comment: Whoot. Downgraded the dot.net compiler nuget package to 2.4.0 and all now works. not sure why.