# Web publish is failing without error description

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have MVC.Net project in VS2015 and I am not able to publish solution to the network folder. I am getting probably connecting error, but connection is ok.

[image]

Have anyone idea what could be a problem ? Once I had similar problem, but it was solved by settings attribute "Copy to local = true" on all referenced libraries, now it does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120812/publish-failed-but-build-succeeded) (SimonGoldstone) fix the issue. I downgraded **Microsoft.Net.Compilers** version from 2.6 to 2.4. I also had to uninstall **Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform** because it references Net.Compilers.