# Problem in Publishing my ASP.NET MVC project using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I am uisng Vsiual Studio 2017 for my project, and when I want to publish the project I get the below error: any one please help.

> Publish has encountered and error! publish failed due to build errors. 
>    
>  
>  A diagnostic  log has been written to the following location: 
>  "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\tem413.temp"

The output log for tem413.temp is

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.b__2()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__108.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.<---

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of the log? What error message is in the Output or Error Window?

Comment: Are your builds successfully?

Comment: You may want to read the error log from tem413.temp

Comment: Yes the build is successfull

Comment: Check the output logs clearly. That will definitely have the error.

Comment: Mr. slFan, in the Error Window I get the error i pasted in my question.. nothing else

Comment: What type of project template did you use? Angular? Asp.net core api? Etc. please explain your project  type since this looks similar to an issue I’ve seen recently..

Comment: Asp.net  MVC 5 not angular

Comment: Possible duplicate : ['Publish failed' but build succeeded?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8120812/4519059) ;).