# Visual Studio Web Apps Publish fails - no errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, build, publish

I have several ASP.Net web form apps in a Visual Studio project. In one of the apps, I was working to add a test page for some additional features we wanted to test before adding to our main pages. Afterwards however, I was trying to publish to our server, but keep getting a message box saying: "The publish has failed due to one or more errors.".

[Build succeeded Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Beyg.png)

[Publish Failed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIfWv.png)

I checked the errors, but none are given. The build was successful and other then a few un-used references, there are no other indicators on what the issue exactly is. We have a few other projects that normally allow for publishing without issues. So I don't believe the issue is from Visual Studio, but I am not completely sure. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 version 14.0.24720.00

Comment: There are things you can try - 1. clean solution and retry. 2. If you use TFS, map another workspace and try publish from there. 3. Get latest patch for your VS version.

Comment: @T.S. Well I tried these, but still without success. Cleaned solution, but the publish still failed. Had a coworker who has access to the project try and republish, but that still failed. I haven't tried getting the latest patch yet (the site to download from said the download was unavailable ). But my coworker was using the latest VS 2017, so I'm not thinking that's the issue. I could keep trying to find the download though, if that still seems like a probable cause.

Comment: Any other suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Aren't you just should click "check for updates" or something like that in VS2015. I don't remember if it has same "flag" that you click for it like VS2017

Comment: Its weird, the notification flag says "there are no notifications". I checked the notification settings, and it should let me know if there are any updates for VS2015 or any packages.  I also clicked the Help button from the top of VS, but it doesn't show any update options. I did some Googling though, it looks like if I want to update to 'version Update 3' I'll have to get a patch from Microsoft directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

There is a Thumbs.db file that was auto-generated in the images folder. I decided to go through the output window line by line to see if I could identify where the publish was failing at. I noticed a line that said the /Images/Thumbs.db file could not be published and that access was denied.

Doing some more online investigating, I found some other questions along the same line as the premise for this one. Specifically the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120812/publish-failed-but-build-succeeded) was most helpful. Tammy Spencer's (@user:973679) answer to try and delete the file was what made the publish succeed. So thank you Tammy.

In addition, the Thumbs.db file wouldn't let me delete it at first. But after doing some more searching, I found this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKTUHn_fEPo) that made the file deletable.